# Define CSS only for enabled input

Tags: jquery, css

How can I define the CSS only for the inputs which are enabled.

I don't want this first solution, because this forces to redefine the enabled style.

```
input[type="text"] {
        background-color: white;
    }
input[type="text"][disabed] {
        background-color: #ECFFEC;
    }
```

This CSS3 solution works, but not for IE :

```
input[type="text"]:enabled {
    background-color: #ECFFEC;
}
```

I tried also with jQuery solution, but this solution fails with *$("input:enabled") is null*

```
$("input:enabled").css("background-color","#ECFFEC");
```

I would prefer a full CSS solution (or tell me which solution is preferred) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using CSS3 and declare 2 styles, mix between soution 1 and 2 : `:enabled:not([readonly])` and `[disabled]`.

```
input[type="text"]:enabled:not([readonly]){
    background-color: #ECFFEC;
}

input[type="text"][disabled] {
    color: black;
}
```

the only bad part is that it does not work with IE but there is no need to override CSS attributes : this is the least worst.

Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 2):

Pure CSS isn't going to work in some of the older browsers, as you've mentioned.  The JavaScript that you tried in your 'jQuery solution' should work, though I'd change it to look like this, that way you can just add the CSS in the CSS file and not in your JS (easier to maintain).

```
$('input:enabled').addClass('foo');
```

As to why it might be returning null, perhaps you're not executing it on DOM ready?

```
$(function() {
    $('input:enabled').addClass('foo');
});
```

Comment: [This solution works](http://jsfiddle.net/j3bAc/69/), but I can't integrate it to my project... I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class .disabled to the disabled element.

```
input[type="text"].disabled {
    background:blue;
}
```

Works in every browser because you don't have to rely on specific selectors.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3bAc/3/).

When you enabled it, you have to remove the class "disabled", and it will get the enabled style.

Comment: the problem is if I add a new attribute to the enabled style, this modify the disabled style too : http://jsfiddle.net/j3bAc/10/. I want to impact only the enabled style...

Comment: Then simply add `class="enabled"` to the enabled one :)

Comment: For sure this works... But I would rather not have to declare a style class on the component... You know what I mean?

Comment: @Jean there's nothing wrong declaring a class in the element, they are really handy and you will find yourself using them most of the time to style elements dinamically.

Comment: I understand, and I have a lot of class style. But this is not what I want in this case (because I take an existing application and I do not want to go on all existing components).

Comment: yes! see my answer in this post. The solution is using CSS3 and declare 2 styles, mix between soution 1 and 2. what do you think of my solution?

Comment: That's good, but in your question you stated a CSS3 solution worked ok except for IE... so I thought you were looking for a CSS2 solution.